# Tor (Relay) observed 2MB/s but I have 10MB/s

Tags: tor

If I go to speedtest.net it shows me 300Mb/s download and 31Mb/s upload.
**Tor still observes that I have 2MB/s** only. Today before nyx recored 3MB/s, Tor still observes 2MB/s. (Now 2.3MB/s)

I have a Nextcloud instance reachable outside of the router, there I have **10MB/s download and upload speed**, my external HDD's maximum.

Why does Tor think that I only have 2MB/s?
I configured Tor for a 20MB/s limit and 30MB/s burst...

Edited to make things clear:
If I download or upload anything from or to my cloud wich is hosted at HOME, I get speeds of 10MB/s. I access my cloud through a PUBLIC IP, DOMAIN: https://cloud.privacyy.ch

Because my ISP, called UPC is very bad, it might take long to make a connection to my cloud since my Internet slows down if too many connection are made (Tor is just killing my internet :(). Sorry for that, trying to fix somehow.

If I go to speedtest.net I get speeds of:

- Upload: 30mbps
- Download: 300mbps

Are these calculated in MB/s (divide by 8??) 3.75MB/s upload Abd 37.5MB/s download? Or are these like mibibits (don't understand them).

Tor always checks the speed of your relay. Now they report that my relay has 2.3MB/s. This can't be since I get a download speed from my local hostet Nextcloud of 11MB/s.

This is how I download stuff from the cloud:

```
$MY COMPUTER <- MY LOCAL NETWORK -> $CLOUD
|                                                                                  |
-----------  MY PUBLIC IP ---------------------------------------
```

So I access my cloud through the public IP, wich actually is 77.59.176.118 BUT $CLOUD in the same network as $MY COMPUTER

That means according to Firefox that uses MB/s that I MUST HAVE 10MB/s minimum download and upload speed, since:
$CLOUD needs upload speed to push the file that I download to $MY COMPUTER
$MY COMPUTER gets the file and uses download

I hope you understand now!
In order to see this shematic you have to 'edit' my post!

Comment: nyx is a tor monitoring tool

Comment: 300 MB/s? Really? That's 3 Gb/s! Or do you mean 300 Mb/s? When comparing speeds the capitalisation is really important (B=bytes vs b=bits), and could potentially be the reason why you think you see an O(10x) difference in speed.

Comment: Does speedtest use MB/s or Mb/s??? I just ran a test there and I have 300MB/s download speed. Isn't this ~0.3GB/s? But my upload speed is much less...
Ok it uses Mbps, prob. Mb/s

Comment: IIRC you can choose which units you want it to present. But the best thing is to look again at what units it's giving you when you run the speed test - Mb or MB. I treat them as 10x difference rather than 8x because it's only an approximation anyway

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=30+mbps+in+mb%2Fs&ia=answer - 30 mbps (my maxiumum upload speed)  is 3.75 MB/s. So.. yeah, maybe I only have 3MB/s. But still, why does my cloud have 10MB/s? I'm using Nextcloud. All should be in MB/s, or does this use Mb/s? probably not.

Comment: Not 30 mbps - you're still mixing capitals and lowercase. M is 10¹²x larger than m. I cannot stress enough that it's vitally important to be accurate when trying to compare speeds

Comment: Nextcloud is using MB/s. If I go to cloud.privacyy.ch I have an upload/download speed of 10MB/s.

Comment: What about nyx (whatever that is?) and Tor?

Comment: TOR is a VPN proxy and it doesn’t matter how fast your connection to your ISP is, your VPN connection will only be as fast as the _slowest_ link in the TOR VPN chain. TOR does not guarantee speed, it is an anonymizing service.

Comment: No. Tor observes that I have 2.3MB/s now. I had 20MB/s before, I saw it. You don't understand Tor. Tor pushes traffic through the relay and looks how fast it is. Your answer will not be accepted since you think that I'm using Tor Browser but I'm hosting a relay and Tor observes the speed that it has wrong.

Comment: Where in your question does it say you're hosting a TOR relay?

Comment: I just thought it is clear because I mentioned nyx and 'observed'.

Comment: I currently have an upload speed (upload to cloud) of 5MB/s (sometimes randomly drops to 5 idk) and a download speed (download from cloud wich is MY UPLOAD SPEED) of 11MB/s.

Comment: I noticed that you looked for it. Thanks. I would like to know if you experience speeds of minimum 5MB/s too.

Comment: "_I get speeds of - Upload: 30mbps - Download: 300mbps_" no you don't. Please capitalise correctly otherwise the numbers are meaningless. I've explained this to you several times

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the asker still won't provide proper consistent speed measurements for a question asking about relative speeds

Comment: I do. Speedtest.net measures 30mbps upload, my cloud has 10MB/s upload speed, hosted at home, Tor observes 2.3MB/s (really not my internet speed).

Comment: I really don't know why I bother. At best "mbps" means millibits per second. Either you mean Mb/s or MB/s, but most definitely not mb/s. If you can't be bothered to read _and act_ on what I have previously explained, I can't help you

Comment: Well... Seems nobody is able to help my. My primary problem is now to limit the connection Tor has. My internet crashed almost (well, the router).

Answer (score 2):

I had a few Tor relays of my own. Your question seems erratic, but I'd like to help a bit, so since you used Nyx already, you know the current input/output of your relay, and I do not really understand what the mystery here is.

If your relay uptime is under ~2 months, then you need to read:

https://blog.torproject.org/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay/

I will quote the starting part:

> A new relay, assuming it is reliable and has plenty of bandwidth, goes through four phases: the unmeasured phase (days 0-3) where it gets roughly no use, the remote-measurement phase (days 3-8) where load starts to increase, the ramp-up guard phase (days 8-68) where load counterintuitively drops and then rises higher, and the steady-state guard phase (days 68+).

I will add that from experience, you do not need to configure any static numbers for the various speed config variables if you want the relay to fully saturate all the bandwidth.

---

To sum it up, the best practices:

- DO NOT EVER run an Exit relay at home. Lawsuits ahead...
- DO NOT run a relay at home. The reason is home routers are not made for so much traffic - open connections. Resulting in crippling your home network for ordinary purposes.
- It is recommended to rent some cheap 100 Mbit/s (symmetric, no limit, no Tor restrictions) VPS, and while this might be difficult to find, I have one recommendation for you, https://www.trabia.com/ (This is no advertisement, based on real-life experience, very cheap choice if on a low budget, admins can be told to make AES-NI instructions available in the VM for both your and their own sake . I had a relay there not long ago, best experience with the support team.)

Comment: Where do you read that the user is trying to set up a Tor relay node? Or, how do you relate you answer to the user's question?

Comment: @they this [throwaway comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684424/tor-relay-observed-2mb-s-but-i-have-10mb-s#comment1293278_684424) :-( It's not anywhere in the question so as far as I'm concerned it's not worth my time updating my answer

Comment: @roaima Huh. That should be in the question.

Comment: Well, I did read this. I do host it at home. Internet dies almost but currently fine with it. If you read this lifecycle post then you can read that every relay is going to be tested about  it's internet speed. Now I have 10MB/s if I download or upload anything to my cloud but Tor says that I have only an internet speed of 2.3MB/s upload/download

Comment: @france1 That's correct because it takes the lower number, in your cause the upload ;) + you run it on home router, and there is always some overhead.

Comment: Ok yes. But speedtest.net says 31mb/s, my cloud has 10MB/s. 31mb/s are 3.75MB/s but since I can download and upload faster than the result of speedtest (to my cloud) it should be at least 10MB/s upload. Why can I upload faster to my cloud?

Comment: And hosting a Tor Relay on a vps is very bad since they monitor your connections you have. It is as bad as hosting it on Windows.

Comment: @france1 I don't get why you contrasted it to Windows, but to the VPS point, there are not many VPS hosters that allow Tor or at least tolerate it, which was exactly my point in the answer. Trabia is one of a few VPS who doesn't care. Pay them 9 Eur for the 2nd cheapest choice and be done with it. I still recommend a non-exit relay to avoid any direct complaints though. They don't care, that simple. Housing a relay at home is a _suicide mission_ as I already tried to point out. If you disagree, just go for it. 

Comment: Well, since I see that my Router dies my primary problem is that I want to limit the connection that Tor is able to make but I'm too dumb... Ipdables doesn't work with Tor idk why. The reason why you should not host a Tor relay on any Windows system is because a) Windows' source is completely closed, b) on GNU.org they have a post wich confirms that Windows detects to what Websites you go if you're using Tor and c) they're enforcing automatic updates and will do something against the relay you use if they can't, because if you host one mid-relay it was confirmed that you can reveal more than

Comment: 50% of the traffic. And additional I don't trust any vps. I have to host it at home.

Comment: @france1 Running Tor on Windows for real? I thought you were joking... I never tried it, and hereby cannot make any comments to that. Well, what can I say now is only to wish you luck!

Comment: I'm running it on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in this answer on the Tor StackExchange, [download speed when using tor browser](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/13976/33870), your Tor connection speed is based on the speed of the slowest link in the circuit. If you go through a node whose owner has limited the throughput to 20Mb/s (2MB/s) then that's the maximum that you'll likely get.

Speeds should usually be quoted in multiples of bits per second (Mb/s, Gb/s). Be aware that Mb (megabits) is around 10x the value of MB/s (megabytes) for the same throughput. 300 Mb/s = 30 MB/s. It's really important that you know which scale of units are being used in any measurement. (Don't worry about multiplying by eight, as in eight bits in a byte, rather than by ten, because you also need to factor in overheads. 10x is quite sufficient for general comparisons - and it's much easier too. Also for approximations it doesn't really matter whether you're measuring in Megabits or Mebibits. Just take the power of ten and you'll be fine.)

Comment: Ok yes that is what speedtest basically says: I habe 3.75MB/s upload speed. But why do I have 10MB/s when I upload something to my cloud?

Comment: 30 Mb/s upload cannot support 100 Mb/s to a cloud service. There's something else in the picture that has not yet been disclosed

Comment: I don't understand it.

Comment: Uh I hate that if I want to make a newline it comments. Please read my edited section of the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I'm done! Was hard on the phone :(.... Do you understand it now @roaima?

Comment: Please delete your answer. You said that you wont update it anymore so why is it still here?